# Solve the linear program

Tags: convex-optimization

Please help to solve this problem. I am new to this type of problems and any help will be greatly appreciated

$$\text{ Minimize } 7x-5y+3z$$

$$\text{ Such that }  \ \ \ 0 ≤ x ≤ 6  , -2 ≤ y  ≤ 7 , -4 ≤ z ≤ 9$$

Comment: I see. Since the volume specified is a brick shape, you just need to check the function at the 8 corner points.

Comment: For practice, in the plane rectangle $0 \leq x \leq 6, \; -2 \leq y \leq 7,$ minimize $3x- 2y.$ You can draw a picture.

Comment: Thanks very much will Jagy  I sort of see what you are saying, but can not work out how 7x - 5y- +3z will be minimized at the corner points

Comment: Well, please do the easier 2 variable example, including drawing on graph paper. You are correct in thinking that there is some detail for you to learn before you know instantly that only a corner works; in more general problems that need not be true, even in a planar problem you could have the minimum at two corners and the entire line segment between them. On the rectangle I gave, minimize $x$ itself!

Comment: Another option is simply to try and get a feel for what increasing/decreasing $x,y,z$ does. As $x$ increases, the function increases. As $y$ increases, the function decreases. What does changing $z$ do? Can you now see which $(x,y,z)$ point must be the answer?